# How do I set the width of the input field of an IntText widget in ipywidgets?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I create an `IntText` widget like this:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
widgets.IntText(value=12, 
       description='CTR1_0', 
       style={'description_width': 'initial'})
```

When I include this widget in an `HBox` in a `Tab`, the text box is much larger than I need.  How do I set it to be 10 characters?

[image]

There is no `width` parameter to [IntText](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html).  I have tried adding `width="10ch"` to the `style` parameter do not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a `Layout` when you instantiate the button, and pass it as a `layout=` kwarg. You can hard code a pixel size, but probably not a character limit.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
w = widgets.IntText(value=12, 
       description='CTR1_0', 
       style={'description_width': 'initial'},
       layout = widgets.Layout(width='100px')
)
# w.layout = widgets.Layout(width='100px')   # or set it later
```