# Changing font size in ipywidgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I've created a IntRangeSlider and the font is a bit too big

```py
# a wrapper for a function i've defined
@interact(my_range = widgets.IntRangeSlider(
    value = [30000, 500000], 
    min = 0, 
    max = 60000, 
    step = 100, 
    description = 'Define the Range: ',
    continuous_update=True
)
         )
```

and here is the outcome :

[image]

the Slider is supposed to show 'Define the range: '
and the max and min are not shown completely and are cut off the by the edges of the Slider area

what can i do?

all i have find online are some HTML or CSS styling that are applied for a `Text` widget.

What is the solution?

Comment: Did you try the ipywidgets documentation for [Layout of Jupyter widgets under the 'Description' heading](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Layout.html#description)? If you look for the text currently written as "may have noticed that long descriptions are truncated", you'll it takes you step-by-step through an example like yours. Likewise, if you search this issue you'll come up with several related examples already posted, such as ...

Comment: <continued>  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72721538/8508004), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67874565/8508004), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67785026/8508004) addressing it by setting 'description_width' to `initial`.